Where should I connect ground in my new service panel?
UPDATE (Progress to Question, with pictures).
Thank you all for your feedback. Here is an update to what I have done since getting feedback both online and offline.
I am going with the 4wire SER Cable from the Disconnect to the inside panel.
Thus, I have bonded at the disconnect. You may see it in my updated picture below. I have also grounded at this disconnect. And finally installed my ground rods.
I have made some improvements as suggested by covering the open knockout and adding some bushings to the main power line 3"PVC.
The hot wire on the right is bent smoother than before.
On the inside panel, I have added more ground bars and you may see where I have attached the 4th wire here.
I have kept the panel up because my wires/home runs will be from the crawl space and not from the vaulted/cathedral ceiling (. I made my crawl space 5.5ft to allow for all my utilities and enable me work there comfortably.)
P.s. My township (small town) apologized for not giving me any information packet when I pulled my electrical permit which would have shed light on some of these questions. They also didn't have any copies for me to pick up but will have an inspector bring a copy during my meter inspection.
Thanks again guys.
Your thoughts would be appreciated again  (be critical, be kind, be merciless, but remember I have never ever done any of this in my life).




ORIGINAL QUESTION (BELOW) 
I am DIYing my house from the ground up and have reached the point of electrical. I am in beautiful rural Michigan.
I mounted my 200amp meter socket. I have also mounted the 200amp disconnect. I also have installed my 200amp panel on the inside.
I used an SEU 4/0 cable with 2 hots and a neutral.
Question 1. Now I am totally confused as to where I need to connect my ground wire (#4).
Question 2. I also don't know where and if I need to bond.
I have never ever done any of this stuff and I appreciate any support.





TL;DR The inside panel is your main panel so it gets the ground
The ground goes at your main panel. In your case, the main panel is the big (but not so big, more below) panel inside. The key is that the outside thing that isn't the meter is only a disconnect. If it were actually a panel then it would likely (but not always) need to have the ground there. Since the outside thing is only a disconnect, and is clearly labeled as such, the panel inside that looks like a main panel really is a main panel.
Which means you run a ground wire, typically 4 AWG copper, to the ground bar in the main panel. While traditionally this has been connected to 2 ground rods, in a new building it is recommended, and often required, that it be connected to an Ufer ground, which is basically a ground rod in the concrete foundation.
It also means that ground and neutral are bonded in the main panel. Because this is the main panel, ground wires can go to the ground bars or to the neutral bars.

A couple of other things to note:
Meter + Disconnect physical layout
This seems a bit suboptimal to me. With the current setup:

Utility service has to loop 180 degrees inside the meter box
Panel feed loops 180 degrees inside the disconnect box
Panel feed loops 180 degrees at the top of the panel

The first two might run afoul of wire bending rules, and I am pretty sure that at least the right hot wire in the disconnect is bent way too much. But even if they don't, I think a much cleaner implementation would be:

Utility service to the bottom of the meter socket
Disconnect feed to the top of the meter socket and out the top of the meter box
Rotate the main panel 180 degrees and feed the cable into the bottom instead of the top

That will eliminate any 180 degree turns of big cable inside any box and change the main panel feed from 90 + 180 to just 90.
Main Panel Size
This looks like a 30 space panel. You may have been sold on it being a 30 space/60 circuit panel, but most circuits now require GFCI (must be at the panel for 240V, can be for 120V) and/or AFCI (almost always at the panel) which are mostly full space breakers, though there are some exceptions available. In addition, surge protection, generator feed (if you want to plan for that), solar, etc. all take up additional spaces. A 42-space or possibly even larger panel would be a very good idea and costs very little extra to do now before you have wired up the branch circuits.

@JeremyParker -- you'll also need to remove the "Service Disconnect" label from the outside breaker, as it isn't the service disconnect (that's indoors in your setup, as the feed from the outside breaker to the inside breaker is 3-wires not 4)

A question for my own education, please: I thought that the first "switch to turn the power off" after the meter was where the ground and neutral should be bonded. Is it the "disconnect" label that makes the outside breaker not the "first switch"? As in if the label wasn't there, that outside breaker box would be the place to bond neutral/ground? Or is my idea of the "first switch" thing wrong?

@Triplefault As I understand it: "Emergency Disconnect" doesn't count as "main panel for grounding etc." On the other "Service Disconnect" arguably counts since "everything past that box is 'regular' service". My understanding is that there is also quite a bit of both (a) variance by jurisdiction, utility, inspector, etc. and (b) quite a bit of leeway as the whole "emergency disconnect required" is relatively new. But I agree the ThreePhaseEel that this would be clearer (and therefore more likely to pass inspection) if it just said "Emergency Disconnect" and not also "Service Disconnect".

Everything needs to be labeled per NEC 230.85.   I would not have done it that way, I would have used a ranch/trailer panel outside and then 4-wire. Just for more versatility.

@Triplefault -- if you look closely at the photo of the OP's inside panel, you'll notice there are only 3 wires (hot, hot, neutral) going into it, which means that the bonding point is at that main panel, and thus the OPs service disconnecting means needs to be there as well (at least for a single-tenant situation)

...or they need different wiring, or metallic conduit, so they do have a separate ground, and the bond goes outside. This is what comes of diving in to DIY things without first doing the "stop and educate yourself" or "ask questions" steps before just doing a thing. Looks like it's all of 6 feet of cable, so not a hugely expensive thing to do over.

Thanks everyone. @Ecnerwal, Lots of assumptions here though. I do believe pros too ask questions. I am more concerned about getting it right, even if it means doing it twice. I was quoted $450k on my 2600sqft home. We are $65k in and already at rough in. Sure, we have had to do somethings twice but we do it safely. While I am asking this question here and a pro here and there, I am also not completely relying on it. Advice, together with what I have read in the code, will give an indication as to where and how I can make it safer, meet or exceeds stands and also pass inspection
